# Adding same random rows to table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following base table:

```
_ID_    _Name_            
1       Bart Smit         
2       Ahmed Lissabon    
3       Medina Aziz
4       Ben Joeson
```

Whereby I would like to assign random titles to above table. However, the same titles should be assigned to the same persons every time the query is run. Thus if I have the following table:

```
_Titles_
Captain
Mr.
Ms.
Prince
King
Queen
Lieutenant
Doctor
Sir
```

So the output could look like this:

```
_ID_   _Title_    _Name_
1      Doctor     Bart Smit
2      King       Ahmed Lissabon
3      Captain    Medina Aziz
4      Sir        Ben Joeson
```

But then it should assign those titles to those names every time I run the code. Now I use the NEWID() in combination with a `CROSS APPLY` and it randomly assigns titles to names every time I run it.

```
SELECT _ID_, R._Title_, _NAME_
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY
     (
         SELECT TOP 1 Title
         FROM #titles
         WHERE TABLE.[_ID_]= TABLE.[_ID_]
         ORDER BY NEWID()
     ) R
```

Comment: When you want that the same titles get assigend to the same persons you could store this matching persistently. Only when a new person is added you would have to insert a new title record for this person.

Comment: @mrPy . . . I'm going to repeat the above comment.  If you want the same values, store the results in a table.  You are attempting to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: If it repeats it is not random.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same result every time instead of just running query, update table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*, R.title AS new_title
  FROM TABLE t
  CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Title
             FROM #titles
             ORDER BY NEWID()) R
  WHERE _TITLE_ IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET _Title_ = new_title;
```

Comment: It's a stored procedure, so if it is going to update the table, it will update it with new titles the next time it deletes and inserts the values again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any random calculation if it has to be repeatable (unless you add a new column to store that random value).

This applies `checksum` and `modulo` to get a repeatable value:

```
select *
from tab
join
 ( select *
     ,row_number() over (order by title) -1 as rn
   from titles
 ) as t
                                    -- or simply hardcoded 9
on abs(checksum(tab.Name,tab.id) % (select count(*) from titles)) = t.rn
;
```

Of course this will still return different when the number of titles changes (or add an ID column to titles).